# "an estimated 75 000 lives"

Tags: articles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   ['A[n] * [number] [plural]' Construction](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9933/an-number-plural-construction)

> Since the Crash Test Dummies, Vince and Larry, were introduced to the American public in 1985, safely belt usage has increased from 21% to 70%, saving an estimated 75 000 lives.

Why is there the article before "estimated" while after it there is the plural form?