# Why do we need an indefinite article in the sentence "The price is **an incredible 50,000 dollars**"?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, articles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [‘A[n] * [number] [plural]’ Construction](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9933/an-number-plural-construction)

Why do we need an indefinite article in the sentence "The price is **an incredible 50,000 dollars**"? "An" is singular, "dollars" is plural.

Answer (score 2):

It’s because the price is one thing, so the fifty grand is being thought of as a single thing, too.  This happens with other things that are thought of as a single unit, despite their multiple components.  Consider:

- The trip was a difficult hundred miles.
- I’ve just had a very painful last three days.
- It’s an easy five more matches, and then you win the trophy.