# The use of ‘other’ vs ‘another’ pronoun

Tags: grammaticality

I am struggling with choosing the suitable pronoun in the following sentence.

> He wrote *other* / *another* two letters in just 15 minutes.

My intuition tells me that in this case, *‘another’* is the pronoun that should be used–as it makes the most sense as far as the context (he has written the letters **in just 15 minutes**) is concerned. But, on the other hand, a friend of mine claims that either the use of *‘other’* here is correct or it is the only option by using which the sentence is grammatically correct.

The question is: are both of these pronouns grammatically **and** logically correct, or is there an only option? If so, which one is it?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: With the current structure of that sentence, only *another* is grammatical. But you could restructure it to admit *other*: "He wrote *two other* letters...".

Comment: Related, I think: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/252173/indefinite-articles-used-with-plural-nouns-it-was-an-amazing-two-days, https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9933/indefinite-article-in-the-an-adjective-number-plural-noun-construc

Answer (score 2):

Say the original sentence was "He wrote two letters"
Another has an article within it (it's an other), so "he wrote another two letters" makes sense
Other doesn't have an article in it already, so "he wrote other two letters" is missing something, but "he wrote the other two letters" is correct.

it's the same for other adjectives too: "He took a big two bites" or "he took the big two bites" but not  "he took big two bites"
it has something to do with adjective order and stuff; either way, you're right on both counts